# Deleting one or two lines with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file containing one function that can start either like this

```
function f1 () {
```

...
or

```
function f1 ()
{
```

...

I'm trying to find a sed command that deletes one line in the first case and two lines in the second case.
I tried using:

```
 sed /function/,/{/d $file
```

but It's not working, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^function f1 ()\s*{/d;N;//d;P;D' file
```

If a line contains the first required string, delete it.

Otherwise, append the following line and test it again.

If the match is true, delete both lines, otherwise print/delete the first and repeat.

N.B. The `//` match uses the last regexp entered and as `\s*` matches zero or more white space (which also includes newlines) the regexp is good for the deletion of either of the two required strings.

An alternative:

```
sed '/^function f1 ()[ \n]*{/d;N;//d;P;D' file
```